# Firefox Crash in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, crash

I use Selenium to do the web-scraping. However, my Firefox browser always crashes after a while (it is very intensive the task of scraping).

The error message from Firefox:

> Firefox had a problem and crashed. We’ll try to restore your tabs and
> windows when it restarts.

The error message from Python:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Tried to run
> command without establishing a connection

I'd like to know if there's a way to deal with that. Ideally, I want something like after Firefox crashes, Selenium would open a new tab and continue from where it crashed.
i tried `try: except:pass` this type of code and they didn't work out.

Comment: maybe catch that specific exception... should be "UnreachableBrowserException"?  Quit and re-initialize the driver (quitting may not actually kill the process but hard to deal with crashes from our end), and send it the last used url... this should launch a new browser and then you can continue.

Comment: also be sure to do some kind of sanity count here so you don't end up in a loop of crashes/restarts....